# Material Design WPF Command Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Material Design for WPF. I am trying to use Dialogs.
Here is my dialog content:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    <Label></Label>
</materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
```

I have also popup box with buttons what generate dialogs. Popup dialog is inside of `DialogHost` as below:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8">
    <materialDesign:PopupBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionAccentPopupBox}" PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignCentres">
        <materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleCheckedContent>
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Close" Width="24">
        </materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleCheckedContent>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button ToolTip="Add Audio" Background="#449AB8" BorderBrush="#449AB8" Command="{Binding AddAudioCommand}">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="White" Kind="Microphone" />
            </Button>  <!-- This Command is working-->

            <Button ToolTip="Add Picture" Background="#449AB8" BorderBrush="#449AB8" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="White" Kind="Camera" />

                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                        <StackPanel Margin="16">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15">
                                Add Image
                            </TextBlock>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsDefault="True" Margin="0 10 10 0" Command="{Binding Path=AddPictureCommand}">
                                Attach from disc
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsCancel="True" Margin="0 8 8 0">
                                Take a photo
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsCancel="True" Margin="0 8 8 0" Command="materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand">
                                <Button.CommandParameter> 
                                    <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                                </Button.CommandParameter>

                                Discard
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                </Button>
            </stackpanel>
...
```

As I understand I am sending `layout` of Dialog to `DialogContent`. However first button's command is working (Add Audio).
Second button 'Add Picture' sends `StackPanel` to `DialogContent`. Dialog is working, it does appear but my Command doesn't work. It's weird because Command to close is working. 
The problem is it doesn't get into Command Execute method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it isn't weird that `CloseDialogCommand` is executing - it indicates to your Dialog.
And you are trying to execute `AddPictureCommand` at context of this Dialog.

Try to find out how to pass your parent as a `DataContext` or maybe (probably better idea) use dedicated MVVM solution to bind content od dialog (your StackPanel) with some code.
There are few solutions of dealing with dialogs on [wiki of MaterialDesign project](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs)